# What is the variance of DFT of Fourier coefficient of difference of a vector of white noise?

Tags: noise, dft, fourier

Consider $\big\{x[0], x[1], \ldots, x[N-1]\big\}$. Suppose,
\begin{cases}
x[n] \sim \mathcal N\left(0, \sigma^2\right)\\
\big\langle x[n], x[n-1]\big\rangle = \frac12 & \forall \ n\\
\big\langle x[n_1],x[n_2]\big\rangle = 0 & \text{whenever}\quad\lvert n_1-n_2\rvert > 1
\end{cases}
I need to compute $\operatorname{Var}\{X[k]\}$ where,
$$
X[k] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] \ e^{-i 2 \pi \frac{nk}{N}}. 
$$
The definition of variance I am using is
$$
\operatorname{Var}\big\{X[k]\big\} = \operatorname{E}\big\{\big\lvert X[k]\big\rvert^2\big\} - \operatorname{E}\big\{\big\lvert X[k]\big\rvert\big\}^2
$$
The second term is zero. But I am failing to compute the variance. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: What does $\big\langle x[n], x[n-1]\big\rangle$ mean to you when $x[n]$ and $x[n-1]$ are random variables?